Hibernate try to set my id field to the current object, what am I doing wrong?
I searched for a long time but I cannot understand what I am doing wrong here.
I'm using spring boot with starter-data-jpa. Versions:

Hibernate: 6.3.1.Final
HikariCP: 5.1.0
springboot dependency management: 1.0.11.RELEASE

My table is initialized with:
create table if not exists test (id bigint not null auto_increment, primary key(id));

I created the class:
package dev.azn9.ektrad.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class TestEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

}

Then I tried to save it:
TestEntity testEntity = new TestEntity();

// For testing purposes only //
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder registryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();

Map<String, Object> settings = new HashMap<>();
settings.put(JdbcSettings.CONNECTION_PROVIDER, HikariCPConnectionProvider.class.getName());
settings.put(JdbcSettings.URL, "...");
settings.put(JdbcSettings.USER, "...");
settings.put(JdbcSettings.PASS, "...");

registryBuilder.applySettings(settings);
StandardServiceRegistry registry = registryBuilder.build();

try (SessionFactory sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry)
        .addAnnotatedClass(TestEntity.class)
        .buildMetadata()
        .buildSessionFactory()) {
    sessionFactory.inTransaction(session -> {
        session.persist(testEntity);
    });
} catch (Exception e) {
    SetupService.LOGGER.error("Cannot create data!", e);
}

I receive the following error:
org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Long dev.azn9.ektrad.model.TestEntity.id] by reflection for persistent property [dev.azn9.ektrad.model.TestEntity#id] : dev.azn9.ektrad.model.TestEntity@1715eda8
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:52) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.BasicEntityIdentifierMappingImpl.getIdentifier(BasicEntityIdentifierMappingImpl.java:158) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4492) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4060) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:293) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.EntityState.getEntityState(EntityState.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityState(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.persist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:766) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:750) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    // ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field dev.azn9.ektrad.model.TestEntity.id to dev.azn9.ektrad.model.TestEntity
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:425) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:48) ~[hibernate-core-6.3.1.Final.jar:6.3.1.Final]
    ... 31 common frames omitted

Please note that I cannot use the autoconfiguration of spring nor the jpa repositories as this is run during the initial setup phase, and the user just provided the connection information via the application.

Your TestEntity missed the getter method of the id field which is required for  jpa entities.
